# Buddhist Perspective on Value, Sentiment, Attraction?

Tags: art

[Paul Bloom: The origins of pleasure](http://www.ted.com/talks/paul_bloom_the_origins_of_pleasure?utm_medium=on.ted.com-facebook-share&awesm=on.ted.com_h0V6i&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_content=awesm-publisher&utm_campaign=&language=en) describe pleasure based on information. To further elaborate original artwork is worth more than a duplicate, how we get attached or less attached to a person on additional information we have, how a artifact gains value because it was used by a famous person, and how you experience pain and pleasure due to additional information you have.  How is this explained through a Buddhist perspective in terms of how attachments works.

Comment: is this not too broad?

Comment: Are you asking, "Why do people like art, why do they find art attractive?" Or are you asking about Buddhist art? Or asking whether music has a role in Buddhist practice? Do people need to watch the referenced Paul Bloom video, in order to answer/understand this question?

Comment: I am asking based on the theory presented in the video mainly. How attachments (Thanha & Upadana) work at a more finer level.

Answer (score 1):

The following gives an in depth explanation of the Jhanas and how at higher levels
Here is a very short excerpt from a long presentation
http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/gunaratana/wheel351.html

> By reflecting upon the second jhana as more tranquil and sublime than
>   the first, the meditator ends his attachment to the first jhana and
>   engages in renewed striving with the aim of reaching the higher stage.
>   He directs his mind to his meditation subject — which must be one
>   capable of inducing the higher jhanas such as a kasina or the breath —
>   and resolves to overcome applied and sustained thought. When his
>   practice comes to maturity the two kinds of thought subside and the
>   second jhana arises. In the second jhana only three of the original
>   five jhana factors remain — rapture, happiness, and one-pointedness.
>   Moreover, with the elimination of the two grosser factors these have
>   acquired a subtler and more peaceful tone.[17]
>
> Besides the main jhana factors, the canonical formula includes several
>   other states in its description of the second jhana. "Internal
>   confidence" (ajjhattamsampasadanam), conveys the twofold meaning of
>   faith and tranquillity. In the first jhana the meditator's faith
>   lacked full clarity and serenity due to "the disturbance created by
>   applied and sustained thought, like water ruffled by ripples and
>   wavelets" (Vism. 157; PP.163). But when applied and sustained thought
>   subside, the mind becomes very peaceful and the meditator's faith
>   acquires fuller confidence.